# Adding NetworkExtension.Framework in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension

I am trying to add Network Extension framework to xcode for implementing Vpn configuration from my application. For that i am referring this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/717/ .From 15:00 onward , video shows how to add Network Extension framework and creating targets after adding the framework. I dont even see NEProviderTemplate.pkg for installation. Is there anything that i have to be done before getting into the frameworks folder??
MacOS Version  OS 10.12

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Screenshot from video
[image]

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that installer is no more available. Because when you select Network Extensions template, the subsequent screen contains all options to select all supported types. As you can see in the following images.

[image: Selection of Network Extension template]

[image: Type of Network Extension]

Answer (score 2):

NEProviderTemplate.pkg is currently removed from os installation.

One solution is take SimpleTunnel app and create from it  your app(with existing NE targets)

Comment: Do you know why it was removed from OS installation?

Comment: @Roberto nope, I don't

Comment: After doing some of my own research, it seems like the NetworkExtension templates (which `NEProviderTemplate.pkg` installed in Xcode) are only, or at least mostly, for supervised devices. Content filtering, per-app VPN and perhaps other features of that framework only work on dev builds and supervised devices for distribution builds. It's possible, and I believe, that the template installer package is only available if you have supervised devices in your organization (school or company).

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed from Mac OS. So you can download that file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByKO5dRSZg8MMmtaSVl0bkdMRk0).

[image]